# Using the cyper-shell to load data and experiencing "connection refused"

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

We have built a series of programs that process data. In the last step, they write out a series of Neo4j commands to create nodes, and later, to connect those nodes. This is a sample of what is created.

```
CREATE (n1:ActionElement { 
  nodekey:1,
  name:'type', 
  resource:  'action',
  element:'ActionElement',
  description:'CompilationUnit',
  linestart:1,
  colstart:7,
  lineend:454, 
  colend:70, 
  content:[],
  level:1,
  end:False
});
```

The issue is that the file created has ~20,000 lines. When I run it through the shell, I get an error on some of the transactions. It seems to alternately process and reject. I cant see a pattern but I am assuming that I am overruning the processing speed.

```
neo4j> CREATE (n1573)-[:sibling]->(n1572);
Connection refused

neo4j> CREATE (n1574)-[:sibling]->(n1573);
Connection refused

neo4j> CREATE (n1575)-[:sibling]->(n1574);
0 rows available after 3361 ms, consumed after another 2 ms
Added 2 nodes, Created 1 relationships

neo4j> CREATE (n1579)-[:sibling]->(n1578);
0 rows available after 78 ms, consumed after another 0 ms*
```

Interesting enough, it recovers, fails, recovers.

Any thoughts ? is this just fundamentally the wrong way to do this ?  The LAST program to touch it happens to be python, should I have it update the database direct ? Thank you

Comment: Do you have something in the `debug.log` when it happens ? Can you share a part of your generated script, because I see some issues (each query = a transaction)

Comment: can you share more lines of your file, specially those that create relationships? and does any of the node creation lines fail too?

Comment: It seems to be a timeout issue. When a transaction went "long" the AWS server dropped the connection. Then eventually caught up and reopened. As logisima quite correctly pointed out,, these were all processed as individual transactions with the implied commit after each one. That was bad form ( Thank you )

Comment: @NoneameCurious - Indeed, it was random for both node creation AND node linkage. One ran for 10K and then failed, one ran for 5 and failed. It really was based on the server. The python I ended up writing ran 1K and then paused for 10 seconds, then ran the next set. That got me through it all. This isnt really a solution but I kicked it to the server admin folks to check the timeouts. Thank you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was a network issue combined with a transaction issue. To solve, we FTPd the file to the same server as the Neo4j instance (eliminating the network latency) and then modified the python load to try/except on error, and if it failed, wait 5 seconds and retry. Only issued an error when the second try failed. That eliminated any 'transaction latency'. On a 16 core machine, it did not fail at all. On a single core, it retried 4 times across 20,000 updates, and all passed on the second try. Not ideal, but workable. 
Thanks